# Use of Equals in generic method

Tags: .net, generics, equals

Anyone can explain this?

```
void Main()
{
    int a = 1;
    short b = 1;

    Console.WriteLine(b.Equals(a));     // false
    Console.WriteLine(a.Equals(b));     // true

    Test<int, short>(a, b); // prints: false, false
    Test(a, b);             // prints: false, false
}

void Test<T1, T2>(T1 x, T2 y)
{
    Console.WriteLine(y.Equals(x));
    Console.WriteLine(x.Equals(y));
}
```

(Wouldn't let me post without adding some more text, so here's some more...)

Comment: Also look at this: [When is the generic type resolved in c#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17734247/when-is-the-generic-type-resolved-in-c)

Comment: and this [why is this generic not resolved at compile time?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6127855/why-is-this-generic-not-resolved-at-compile-time)

Comment: Looking at the IL, the code in the generic method is always boxed, while the code in the "main" method is not.

Answer (score 3):

Your three calls return `false` because they call `Object.Equals(Object)`.

You're comparing a boxed `Int32` with a boxed `Int16` (`short`), so they're two unequal objects and it returns false.
The [overrides](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/int32.cs,72) of `Equals(Object)` first check that the boxed object they receive is of the same exact type, which `Int16` isn't.

`a.Equals(b)` calls [`Int32.Equals(Int32)`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/int32.cs,80), implicitly converting `b` to `Int32` at compile time.
Therefore, that method sees two `Int32`s with the same value and returns true.

Answer (score 2):

The IL shows this: The first call is boxed:

```
IL_0000:  nop         
IL_0001:  ldc.i4.1    
IL_0002:  stloc.0     // a
IL_0003:  ldc.i4.1    
IL_0004:  stloc.1     // b
IL_0005:  ldloca.s    01 // b
IL_0007:  ldloc.0     // a
IL_0008:  box         System.Int32
IL_000D:  call        System.Int16.Equals
IL_0012:  call        System.Console.WriteLine
IL_0017:  nop         
IL_0018:  ret
```

The second is not:

```
IL_0000:  nop         
IL_0001:  ldc.i4.1    
IL_0002:  stloc.0     // a
IL_0003:  ldc.i4.1    
IL_0004:  stloc.1     // b
IL_0005:  ldloca.s    00 // a
IL_0007:  ldloc.1     // b
IL_0008:  call        System.Int32.Equals
IL_000D:  call        System.Console.WriteLine
IL_0012:  nop         
IL_0013:  ret
```

The IL generated for the generic method is always boxing:

```
Test<T1,T2>:
IL_0000:  nop         
IL_0001:  ldarga.s    02 
IL_0003:  ldarg.1     
IL_0004:  box         T1
IL_0009:  constrained. T2
IL_000F:  callvirt    System.Object.Equals
IL_0014:  call        System.Console.WriteLine
IL_0019:  nop         
IL_001A:  ldarga.s    01 
IL_001C:  ldarg.2     
IL_001D:  box         T2
IL_0022:  constrained. T1
IL_0028:  callvirt    System.Object.Equals
IL_002D:  call        System.Console.WriteLine
IL_0032:  nop         
IL_0033:  ret
```

and a call to this method is done with:

```
IL_0000:  nop         
IL_0001:  ldc.i4.1    
IL_0002:  stloc.0     // a
IL_0003:  ldc.i4.1    
IL_0004:  stloc.1     // b
IL_0005:  ldarg.0     
IL_0006:  ldloc.0     // a
IL_0007:  ldloc.1     // b
IL_0008:  call        Test<Int32,Int16>
IL_000D:  nop         
IL_000E:  ret
```

so, even when the type is known at compile time, the values will still be boxed.